# Integrate passport.js from node server file to routes file

Tags: node.js, express, routes, passport.js

I'm currently trying to utilize passport in my node server for twitter auth on a project. When I have all the code in one server file passport functions as expected. Below is an excerpt from the server file with all the routes in it:

```
passport.use(new TwitterStrategy({
  consumerKey: config.twitter.consumer_key, 
  consumerSecret: config.twitter.consumer_secret, 
  callbackURL: config.twitter.callback_url.dev
}, (token, tokenSecret, profile, done) => {
  console.log(token, tokenSecret, profile, done);
  process.nextTick(() => {
    return done(null, profile);
  });
}));

app.use(session({ secret: 'SOMESECRET' }));
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '../public')));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

// expose to routes 
app.all('*', (request, response, next) => {
  request.log = log;
  next();
});

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.render('pages/index.ejs');
});

// twitter auth endpoint 
app.get('/auth/twitter', passport.authenticate('twitter'));

// twitter auth callback endpoint 
app.get('/auth/twitter/callback', passport.authenticate('twitter', { failureRedirect: '/' }), (req, res) => {
  res.redirect('/');
});
```

However, when I try to expose passport from the server file to the routes file the authentication never occurs. I've searched most of the questions here and went back to the doc but all the tutorials show one server file with all the routes in it.

Server file:

```
passport.use(new TwitterStrategy({
  consumerKey: config.twitter.consumer_key, 
  consumerSecret: config.twitter.consumer_secret, 
  callbackURL: config.twitter.callback_url.dev
}, (token, tokenSecret, profile, done) => {
  console.log(token, tokenSecret, profile, done);
  process.nextTick(() => {
    return done(null, profile);
  });
}));

app.use(session({ secret: 'SECRET' })); // session secret
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '../public')));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

// expose to routes 
app.all('*', (request, response, next) => {
  request.log = log;
  request.passport = passport;
  next();
});

// routes 
app.use('/', routes);
```

Routes file:

```
import express from 'express';
const routes = express.Router();
import config from '../config.js';

// main
routes.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.render('pages/index.ejs');
});

// twitter auth endpoint 
routes.get('/auth/twitter', (req, res) => {
  const passport = req.passport;
  passport.authenticate('twitter');
});

// twitter auth callback endpoint 
routes.get('/auth/twitter/callback', (req, res) => {
  const passport = req.passport;
  passport.authenticate('twitter', {
    failureRedirect: '/'
  });
  res.redirect('/');
});


module.exports = routes;
```

What am I missing here? I'm guessing I cannot use `passport.authenticate` inside the function for the route. I'm still trying to figure out how to get the version using the routes file working. Any help is appreciated!!

Comment: Why do you to redifine the route on route file again and what about your logs

Comment: uhm im unclear what you're asking @douxsey? the routes file is shown because there are two attempts at making this work as I described in my post. Also the post is not about logs, I dont see how that factors in to my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can require **Passport** normally no need to get passport by `let passport = req.passport`. Here is my small demo for Google Oauth by passport
**Routes.js**

```
const router = require('express').Router();
const passport = require('passport');

router.get(
    '/google',
    passport.authenticate('google', {
        scope: ['profile', 'email'],
        session: false
    })
);
router.get(
    '/google/callback',
    passport.authenticate('google', {
        session: false
    })
);
```

**Server.js**

```
// passort config
app.use(passport.initialize());
require('./services/passport'); // contains the passport google strategy
// routes
require('./routes')(app);
```

Comment: So the first line in your server.js file `app.use(passport.initialize());` does that imply that you have also run `const passport = require('passport');` in your server.js file as well?

Comment: Nevermind my above comment - i see what you were getting at and was just overthinking this. Will accept this as the solution, my mistake was small and stupid  :)